# How can I change environment for the tablet device?

Tags: javascript, java, android, cordova, weblogic

I have a ***webservice app***, and this is connected to an android device to create "inspections". Once you have created it, there are options to "synchronize", which allows you to upload this inspections to the webservice through a REST service. The problem is that I have a different environment and I want the android device to work on my local environment (development) and not in previous environment as actually.

I have the device connected with localhost using "chrome://inspect/#devices" tool.  Also, I have changed the "baseUrl" in app-config file. Now, the main problem is that I can't login on the device app, but the localhost on browser works.

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: what changes did you make on the `baseUrl`? seems like that is where you should look. and if the web service is hosted on a particular port number like `:3000` or `:5000`, you can use that to troubleshoot and search for clues.

Comment: I remplaced the main baseUrl for my localhost:8081